# cmder - Command to open split cmder

Tags: cmd, cmder

I've searched everywhere and I can't seem to find (what should be simple) a command that opens 2 cmder windows side by side:
[image]

**And run my own commands in each one.**

How can I do that using commands only?

Comment: https://youtu.be/C0vwBXoWhms

Comment: https://superuser.com/questions/593612/run-series-of-commands-in-different-tabs-in-conemu

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I eventually found the answer in the [ConEmu github pages](http://conemu.github.io/en/SplitScreen.html) (sort of) by using the `-new_console:s` flag.

```
start cmd /k  "foocommand"
start cmd -new_console:s /k "barcommand"
```

Run the above commands from cmder and it works. The only problem is that it doesn't automatically open cmder, and you have to run it from cmder but at least it works. Starting a `cmd` from `cmder` opens a `cmder` automatically.

Answer (score 1):

One can right click on the top of Cmder and do as shown below snapshot
[image]

Answer (score 0):

... ok since there is no "real" answer in here, I thought I'll post my solution:

if you execute the line below in a windows cmd (exchanging `Cmder.exe`with the path to the `Cmder.exe`) it will do just what you've asked for without having to mess around in the cmder gui

```
Cmder.exe /x "-run cmd" & Cmder.exe /x "-run -new_console:s cmd"
```